# Failed attempts to read XML from goodreads API using requests and lxml

Tags: python, xml, api, python-requests, lxml

Goodreads claims I can get XML that begins with a root called `<GoodreadsResponse>`, whose 1st child is `<book>`, the 8th child of which is `image_url`. Trouble is, I can't event get it to recognize the proper root (it prints `root` not `GoodreadsResponse` and fails to recognize that the root has any children at all, though the response code is 200. I prefer to work with JSON and, allegedly, you can convert it to JSON, but I had zero luck with that.

Here's the function I have at the moment. Where am I going wrong?

```
def main(url, payload):
    """Retrieves image from Goodreads API endpoint returning XML response"""
    res = requests.get(url, payload)
    status = res.status_code
    print(status)
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
    tree = etree.fromstring(res.content, parser=parser)
    root = etree.Element("root")
    print(root.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/", '{"isbns": "0441172717", "key": "my_key"}')
```

The goodreads info is here:

```
**Get the reviews for a book given an ISBN**
Get an xml or json response that contains embed code for the iframe reviews widget that shows excerpts (first 300 characters) of the most popular reviews of a book for a given ISBN. The reviews are from all known editions of the book. 
URL: https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/ISBN?format=FORMAT    (sample url) 
HTTP method: GET
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are receiving HTML not XML with your request.
You need to set the format of the response you want: `https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/ISBN?format=FORMAT`

And you need to use params not payload:
[Constructing requests with URL Query String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788445/constructing-requests-with-url-query-string-in-python)

P.S. For the request you are doing you can use JSON. 
https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show_by_isbn

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked best for me:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def main():
    key = 'myKey'
    isbn = '0441172717'
    url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/{}?key={}'.format(isbn, key)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml-xml")
    print(soup.find('image_url').text)
```

The issue was that XML contents were wrapped in  tags. Using the Beautiful Soup 'lxml-xml' parser, rather than 'lxml' retained the content included in CDATA tags and allowed them to be parsed correctly.