# Dynamically parsing the q as an user input to search news in News API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have wrote the code which searches for particular keyword and give the news through news API but I have hard coded the q
(Keywords or phrases to search for in the article title and body.) But I want it should be dynamic like user give a keyword to search and it provides everything. Can anyone please help me.
Below is the code snippet which i am doing.

```
import requests
url = ('http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q=Python&'
       'from=2020-08-17&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=xxxxxxx')

response = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing requests with URL Query String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788445/constructing-requests-with-url-query-string-in-python)

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe ,it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve your query,

```
import requests
What=input("Enter the q: ")
url = ('http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       f'q={What}'
       'from=2020-08-17&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=xxxxxxx')

response = requests.get(url)
```

This code will ask user to enter q, store it in "What" variable and hence can be dynamically changed

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil  I got the error with little twig in the solution you provided and it worked . Posting it for broader audience

import requests
What=input("Enter the q: ")
url = ('http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'
       'q='+What+'&'
       'from=2020-08-17&'
       'sortBy=popularity&'
       'apiKey=XXXXXXXXXX')