# Constructing URL with Python Requests Library

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert a curl command into a python request call, however, it will not work for me.

I am following this answer for reference: [Constructing requests with URL Query String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788445/constructing-requests-with-url-query-string-in-python)

The curl command is:

```
curl -g 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?' --data-urlencode 'match[]=up'
```

And the request call

```
import requests

params = {
    'data-urlencode': "match[]=up",
}
r = requests.get("http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?", params=params)
```

I've tried different variations of the parameters, however, none will work for me.....

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this out -> https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, unfortunately still not working.....

Comment: *not working* how?

Comment: I get the following output with curl (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f0NyZio5cpy4gt0JvQ2LtXbH4TyYrL5W/view?usp=sharing) and when using the output of the response generator (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K_nXO2r5KbnXPtqcaElqnN99rqmb0lXS/view?usp=sharing)